# Issue with pure function when mapping dynamic content within graphics scope

Tags: graphics, dynamic, map

What I am trying to achieve can be described using following code:

```
vector = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};
Graphics[Circle[#, 1] & /@ vector]
```

In the above, a pure function is applied to Map given vector to construct a set of Circle objects. Same type of logic is applied below, however it does not compile and throws an error:

> Coordinate {{0, 0}, {1, 0}} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form

Code:

```
DynamicModule[
 {vector, range, radius},
 (*Parameters*)
 radius = 5;
 range = {{0, 100}, {0, 100}};
 vector = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};

 EventHandler[
  Show[
   Graphics[{
     (*Composition*)
     Line[Dynamic[vector]],
     Circle[#, radius] & /@ Dynamic[vector] (*Error*)
     }],
   (*Options*)
   PlotRange -> range, Axes -> True],
  {
   (*Events*)
   "MouseClicked" :> (AppendTo[vector, MousePosition["Graphics"]])
   }
  ]
 ]
```

Why does MMA generates the error stated above and how can it be bypassed? Essentially, I want to have a Circle around ea. Point which forms part of the Line.

Comment: `Dynamic[vector]` is incorrect usage. Best way to always think about `Dynamic` is that it dynamically updates pixels on the screen. When you consider that definition it should be apparent why `Dynamic[vector]` is incorrect. The next problem that arises from that usage is that the syntax for `Circle` becomes incorrect which is why you see the pink boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When mapping a vector onto `Circle` it needs to be just that, a vector with `Head` `List`. Putting `Dynamic` outside of `Graphics` will allow you to see the circles as they update. Alternatively wrap it around the mapping onto `Circle`. Additionally your use of `Show` is redundant.

```
DynamicModule[{vector, range, radius},
radius = 5;range = {{0, 100}, {0, 100}};vector = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};

EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Line[Dynamic[vector]], 
    Dynamic[Circle[#, radius] & /@ vector]},
   PlotRange -> range, Axes -> True],
{"MouseClicked" :> (AppendTo[vector, MousePosition["Graphics"]])}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You say to put Dynamic outside of Graphics. That is not consistent with your example. Typo?

Comment: @JackLaVigne you can have it outside of `Graphics` or wrapped around the mapping onto `Circle`.

Answer (score 4):

You need just a single `Dynamic` in front of `Show`. Because, as stated in the documentation,

> Dynamic does its work entirely in the front end, you cannot
>   use it inside functions that need to access the value of an expression
>   in order to do their work.

Prepend `Show` with `Dynamic`, will update the graphics output whenever there is a change in the values of the variables used inside:

```
DynamicModule[
 {vector, range, radius},
 (*Parameters*)
 radius = 5;
 range = {{0, 100}, {0, 100}};
 vector = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};

 EventHandler[
    Dynamic@Show[
       Graphics[{
          (*Composition*)
          Line[vector],
          Circle[#, radius] & /@ vector
       }]
      (*Options*)
      ,PlotRange -> range
      ,Axes -> True
     ]
    ,(*Events*)
    {"MouseClicked" :> (AppendTo[vector, MousePosition["Graphics"]])}
 ]
]
```

[image]